# FormClosing, OnFormClosed, ETC... Not firing on ( X ) C#

Tags: c#, events

Alright, so I've got this program I'm trying to write.  No company is going to rely on it or anything, so I'm not too caring that the threading here is almost positively poor practice.

My issue is that none of the "Form Closing Events" that I have found on this site and on MSDN are firing for me.

In my code, I have very hopeful console outputs that will notify me if the code has been run, but none of the events that I've found do such.

Can someone slap me into the reality of what it takes to get this to work?  I know I must me missing something simple here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace CMDRunner
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        IDataObject clippy = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        String TClippy;
        bool isRunning = true;
        //Thread worker;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try
            {
                TClippy = Clipboard.GetText();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += e.ToString() + "\n";
            }
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        timer.Interval = 500;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //worker = new Thread(KeyChecker);
        //worker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        //worker.Start();

        System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
        ToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.checkBox1, "Hides anything you run.");
        richTextBox2.Text += Clipboard.GetText();
    }



    void KeyChecker()
    {
        while (isRunning)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(40);
            if ((Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.Return) & KeyStates.Down) > 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += "Enter Key Clicked!!!\n";
                Console.WriteLine(isRunning);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I will fire the events here

        if (Clipboard.ContainsText() == true && TClippy != Clipboard.GetText())
        {
            try
            {
                TClippy = Clipboard.GetText();
                Clipboard.GetImage();
                richTextBox2.Text = TClippy;
                richTextBox3.Text = TClippy + "\n***************************************\n^^^End Clipboard item above^^^\n***************************************\n" + richTextBox3.Text;
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += er.ToString() + "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sendCommand();
    }

    public void sendCommand()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            }
            else
            {
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            }
            startInfo.FileName = textBox1.Text;
            startInfo.Arguments = textBox2.Text;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            richTextBox1.Text += textBox1.Text + " \"" + textBox2.Text + "\"\n";
        }
        catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            richTextBox1.Text += "ERROR: Could not find: " + textBox1.Text + "\n";
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "No input provided\n" ;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += e.ToString() + "\n";
        }
    }

    //UserActivityHook actHook;


    /*private void Checker(object arg)
    {
        // Worker thread loop
        for (;;)
        {
            if (StopRequest.WaitOne(300)) return;
            richTextBox1.Text += Clipboard.GetText() + "\n";
        }
    }*/


    //******************************************************************************************************************************
    //Nothing below ever runs.....
    //******************************************************************************************************************************
    private void Form1_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        isRunning = false;
        Console.WriteLine(isRunning);
        Console.WriteLine("CLOSING");
        //worker.Join();
        //e.Cancel = true;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        isRunning = false;
        Console.WriteLine(isRunning);
        Console.WriteLine("CLOSING");
        //worker.Join();
        //e.Cancel = true;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.Equals((sender as Button).Name, @"CloseButton"))
        {
            // Do something proper to CloseButton.
            isRunning = false;
            Console.WriteLine(isRunning);
            Console.WriteLine("CLOSING");
            //worker.Join();
        }
        else
        {
            isRunning = false;
            Console.WriteLine(isRunning);
            Console.WriteLine("CLOSING");
            // Then assume that X has been clicked and act accordingly.
        }
    }

    private void Form1_OnFormClosed(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        isRunning = false;
        Console.WriteLine(isRunning);
        Console.WriteLine("CLOSING");
        //worker.Join();
        //e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events

Comment: @kirodge is the winner.  Thanks.  Damn I feel dumb haha.